# What's the equivalent of the >> Java operator in C#

Tags: c#, java

I'm converting some Java code to C# and I came across the >> operator. What is that operator called and what is the equivalent in C#?

I'm trying to convert the following code:

```
final int pointerIndex = (action & ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
```

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you are facing issues with that "final" keyword? In C#, final's equivalent is 'readonly' ( or 'const' ). However, unlike in Java ( iirc ), readonly cannot be used on variables that are defined inside a method or on method parameters. 'const' on the other hand can be used on variables that are defined inside a method.

Comment: @JaakkoLipsanen the problem was with something else and I didn't read the compiler error. I was using enums which are not valid for shift operations. Simple casting to int did the trick.

Comment: @KirkWoll exactly what I did.

Comment: @Jonas, I'm an idiot.  Sorry for not reading the last sentence of your previous comment. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the right-shift operator, and it's the same in C#.

Comment: @LewsTherin Andrew typed more characters hahaha, matter of secs.

Comment: @BrOSs Text speak from now on. Promise :) Anyway +1

Comment: Aww man, he gets more upvotes than me, though I have linked the documentation :P

Comment: +1 to all :) Come on, even JavaScript have the same one... as other curly brace languages starting from C.

Comment: It turns out I didn't read the compiler error. It was related to something else. I did learn the name of the operator, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It is a basic [shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) available in many programming languages. In C# it is the same as in Java.

Comment: I found a newer version of the MSDN documentation and linked this one instead one old page from 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Never used this but here's the msdn link :[C# shift](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)